# Apache is "Unable to initialize module" because of module's and PHP's API don't match after changing the PHP configuration

Tags: apache, memcached, php

php -v gives this

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: memcache: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: memcache: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20060613
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match in Unknown on line 0
bogus test name tests/
```

ps. i've upgraded from php 5.2 to 5.3. before this everything worked okay.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

When you update the version of PHP *(especially when going from version X.Y to version X.Z)*, **you must update the PHP extensions** as well.

This is because PHP extensions are developped in C, and are "close" to the internals of PHP -- which means that, if the APIs of those internals change, the extension must be re-compiled, to use the new versions.

And, between PHP 5.2 and PHP 5.3, for what I remember, there have been some modifications in the internal data-structures used by the PHP engine -- which means extensions must be re-compiled, in order to match that new version of those data-structures.

How to update your PHP extensions will depend on which system you are using.

If you are on windows, you can find the `.dll` for some extensions here : http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

For more informations about the different versions, you can take a look at what's said on the left-sidebar of [windows.php.net](http://windows.php.net/).

If you are on Linux, you must either :

- Check what your distribution provides
- Or use the `pecl` command, to re-download the sources of the extensions in question, and re-compile them.

Comment: that's what i actually thought i should do. I have openSUSE 11.2
unfortunately, my distr. doesn't provide anything, what should I do to recompile php or its extensions -- google gives a lot thought scattered info... thx.

Comment: You probably don't need to recompile PHP itself : you have already updated it ;; to re-install/compile the extensions, the simplest way *(at least for memcache)* will be the pecl command ;; something like `pecl upgrade memcache`, I suppose, might do the trick *(You'll need what's required to build/compile stuff)* ;;; for more informations, you can take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php

Comment: i tried to recompile php and all my module and nothing worked, but somehow "pear install -f pecl/memcache" did the trick for me :)

anyway, thank you)

Comment: Well, glad you found a solution :-)

Comment: I had the same problem and I tried `pecl upgrade <modulename>` but I got the error "ERROR: ``make`` failed" , I also tried `pear install -f pecl/<modulename>` and I got the same error :( any help please

Comment: Is there some other source/repository for dll files? I checked in http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ but couldn't find. I need two dll files `php_pdo.dll` and `php_mcrypt.dll`. I have a pre-compiled instance of PHP on my system and cannot even run PHP on command line. Please check http://serverfault.com/questions/397885/i-have-an-already-compiled-instance-of-php-how-do-i-get-compatible-versions-of if you can help. I got downvoted there and am not sure if I can ask that in SO.

Answer (score 10):

just

```
pecl uninstall module_name
```

then

```
pecl install module_name
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked for me! I'd tried `pecl upgrade-all` but I guess there's no newer version of my module so it didn't trigger a recompile.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is within the php5-dev package. I guess you went from php5.2 on an older linux version to php5.3. I did the same thing, and when I managed to install php 5.3 there was a conflict with php5-dev. For some reason it doesn't get upgraded to the new version. Dunno why is that and I don't care, however this makes your extension compiled with the older API version, while php ofc is with the newer api version. What I did to solve this problem was:

I removed php5-dev with 
`sudo apt-get remove php5-dev`, then I ran `sudo apt-get autoremove` to get rid of the leftovers that were giving me the trouble, and after that I just installed php5-dev again.
`sudo apt-get install php5-dev`.

Once that was done, I removed my memcache with `sudo pecl uninstall memcache` and installed it again `sudo pecl install memcache`. Now both the module and the php had the same api version so I knew right away that I had the issue solved :)

Hope it  helps.

Comment: This really helped me to install `pecl/zmq` extension. I have upgraded recently from `php5.3` to `php5.4` and the `php5-dev` was not upgraded as well.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that the modules are installed, but your PHP.ini still points to an old directory.

Check the contents of /usr/lib/php/extensions.  In mine, there were two directories: no-debug-non-zts-20060613 and no-debug-non-zts-20060613.  Around line 428 of your php.ini, change:

extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613"

to

extension_dir = "/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626"

Then restart apache.  This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this issue for a long time and found out that when you run configure, just pass it the path to the correct `php-config` tool.

In my case, it was

```
./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/zend/bin/php-config
```

... If you're unsure, run a `locate php-config` on your machine and find the right one amongst the different versions installed.

Hope this helps somebody in the future.

PS. My default `php-config` was set to 20090926 which is PHP 5.3.  The one I manually entered as a param for `./configure was` for PHP 5.4 (2010...)

Comment: In my case I had to do /usr/local/zend/bin/phpize first, and then ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/zend/bin/php-config

Answer (score 1):

I had this part enabled in my php.ini

```
 extension=php_memcache.dll
    [Memcache]
    memcache.allow_failover = 1
    memcache.max_failover_attempts=20
    memcache.chunk_size =8192
    memcache.default_port = 11211
```

After commenting these lines composer was installed in my windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue after upgrading from PHP 5.5 to PHP 5.6. The `phpize` and `php-config` libraries being used to compile the phalcon extension were still the ones from PHP 5.5. I had to run the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-dev
```

There will be a long stacktrace, the key information I saw was this:

```
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php-config5.6 to provide /usr/bin/php-config (php-config) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/phpize5.6 to provide /usr/bin/phpize (phpize) in auto mode
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same error even after recompiling the modules.

But I solved it you just have to specify the absolute path of your phpize.

Answer (score 0):

Before you phpize, make sure to update your path ($PS1) to point to the new PHP! phpize uses your environment, and if you still have vestiges of your old PHP in your path or other parts of the environment, things will get hairy!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one that works with php 5.5. Download xampp 1.8.3 from [here](http://www.apachefriends.org/download.php?xampp-win32-1.8.3-1-VC11.zip) and download memcache dll from [here](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/memcache/3.0.8/php_memcache-3.0.8-5.5-ts-vc11-x86.zip)

Answer (score 0):

In my case in **php.ini**

```
[CLDbg]
extension=php_cl_dbg_5_3_VC9.dll
clport=6000
```

I removed Codelobster which support different PHP version, so need to update to:

```
[CLDbg]
;extension=php_cl_dbg_5_3_VC9.dll
;clport=6000
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has just happened to me and has been solved simply by increasing 
memory_limit from 32 M to 64 M
You can adjust the value on the file where php.ini exists

locate php.ini
then choose the right file and search for memory_limit and after modifying it 
you must reboot the apache
/etc/init.d/httpd restart

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used lnmp to install php with version 5.4.45. But maybe because I installed php5-dev after lnmp (which I guess is not necessary if you installed lnmp), my phpize and php-config both point to older version tools than php.
I solved this by change the soft link of `/etc/alternatives/phpize` and `/etc/alternatives/php-config` to `/usr/local/php/bin/phpize` and `/usr/local/php/bin/php-config`.
Hopes this is helpful.

Answer (score -4):

What worked for me was simply to do the following:

open the php.ini file.

Under the DYNAMIC EXTENSIONS heading, comment out the following line as

```
;extension=php_java.dll
```

Restarted Apache and all was fine

Comment: This just disables an extension, preventing any attempt at loading it. The question is about getting an extension to start working again.