# Confusion about installing PHP Memcache

Tags: php, memcached

I'm working on Win7(x64), using PHP 5.3. 
I had installed memcached, and the this service is running with port 11211 . And the *php_memcache.dll* had been copy into *ext* folder and added this extension into the *ini* file properly. But application always report the error *'The Memcache Extension must be loaded to use Memcached Cache'* and Memcache can not be used.

I knew the difference between Memcache and Memcached, and I have tried many types of memcache and php extensions, finally, it's not working as always.

Comment: Is memcache showing in phpinfo(); ?

Comment: What's your extension_dir? Check the dll really is in that folder - then check your logs to see if there's any startup errors. Obvious check is did you restart your webserver?

Comment: Yes, Martin, I have configured the extension correctly, because there was MySql extension in the same folder and MySql is working. No starup error.  I have restarted webserver many times.  --- Sorry, I found a error 'PHP Startup: memcache: Unable to initialize module'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're getting is typically caused due to an incompatible version ([`Possible duplicate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394532/apache-is-unable-to-initialize-module-because-of-modules-and-phps-api-dont)).

You could upgrade from 5.3 to 5.4.6 [`here`](http://windows.php.net/download/) and either build memcache yourself or try [`this dll`](http://stalk.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/php-5.4.0-Win32-VC9-x86.zip).

Alternatively you can try [`this dll`](http://shikii.net/blog/downloads/php_memcache-cvs-20090703-5.3-VC6-x86.zip) for your current installation of PHP.

It's unfortunate but there is no maintained version of PECL binaries for windows. You should consider joining us privileged ones on a *nix environment :)