# how to install php_sdo with xampp lite

Tags: php, xml, apache, dll

Actually I was using `SDO_DAS_XML::create();` function in my php code and it requires `php_sdo.dll`. So I install it from net and save this at `C:\xampplite\php\ext` location after that I add this to my `php.ini` file. But it still not working even when I start apache from xampp it shows warning 
`PHP Startup: sdo: Unable to inilialize module`. *Module compiled with module *API =20060613*. PHP compiled with module API=20090626.* These options need to match.`

Please help me how to add `php_sdo` with my xampp. I am using windows xp.

Answer (score 0):

what i conclude from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394532/apache-is-unable-to-initialize-module-because-of-modules-and-phps-api-dont) is that the dll file you downloaded might be compiled for a version of PHP older to the one you have..you can try [this dll file](http://ioosd.in/download/php_sdo.dll) as it's not giving me problem with PHP 5.3.1

Comment: sorry rishi it also shows error now when I start apache server from xampp control panel is shows "The application or DLL C:\xampplite\php\ext\php_sdo.dll is not a valid windows image. please check this against your installation diskette."

Comment: i am having XAMPP (Basis Package) version 1.7.3..and apache starts without any error..i hv not tested this dll file with xampplite..