# Access forbidden to all sites after upgrading PHP from 5.3 to 5.6

Tags: php, apache, centos

I just followed some steps to get this new version of PHP running on my production server, and after that I cannot access any site anymore.

I checked and the only modified configuration file is etc/php.ini so nothing about Apache should have changed.

My server is a CentOS 5.11.

When I use:

```
php -v
```

I get this result:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ffmpeg: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20131226
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0
PHP 5.6.19 (cli) (built: Mar  3 2016 08:14:44)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```

Thanks

Comment: Could it be a problem related to modules from the previous version?

Comment: Well. the message is quite clear. The ffmpeg module you're using uses an older API than is required by the new PHP version.

Comment: So what would be your advise about how to fix the problem? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that maybe this has been addressed elsewhere on Stackoverflow:

[apache-is-unable-to-initialize-module-because-of-modules-and-phps-api-dont](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394532/apache-is-unable-to-initialize-module-because-of-modules-and-phps-api-dont)

That might help.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I already checked that thread and nothing from there helps me. I just went through the whole php.ini previous file, comparing it with the new one and the very few differences that I found I modified without success.

Comment: There were a couple of things in there that seemed like they might work.  "pecl uninstall module_name, then pecl install module_name" or "This problem has just happened to me and has been solved simply by increasing memory_limit from 32 M to 64 M You can adjust the value on the file where php.ini exists"