# How to fix PHP module problems after update

Tags: php, macos

I think this question is asked already, but with so many different conditions, I think my problem is a bit unique, correct me if I'm wrong.

I have this response after make a PHP update on my old MacBook. Using curl PHP install command:

```
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3
```

and this is my result after install and I check my version with "PHP -v" command on terminal

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: curl: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20160303
PHP    compiled with module API=20180731
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

Warning: PHP Startup: curl: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20160303
PHP    compiled with module API=20180731
These options need to match
 in Unknown on line 0

etc
```

also in the end of the line there is this error:

```
Deprecated: Directive 'track_errors' is deprecated in Unknown on line 0
PHP 7.3.0beta3 (cli) (built: Sep  3 2018 11:26:01) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.0-dev, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

PHP 7.3.0beta3 is my previous version.

Been tried to re-install the same version of PHP using command line but still doesn't work.

```
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3.0beta3
```

I know something un-match with the version. But how exactly I fix it.
I've been search the whole internet, and not found any solution that works well with me. Most question that I search here, is not marked as "worked solution" yet.
Probably I understand it wrong.

Anyone have the solution, please?!
I desperately need the answer. Thank you

FYI:
My MacOS is Yosemite 10.10.5

////////////////////

**UPDATE 1:**
I've been checked on this solution on **[THIS LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394532/apache-is-unable-to-initialize-module-because-of-modules-and-phps-api-dont)**

But it's not going to work since the solution require me to install PECL / PEAR, and that installer would work through PHP command. Which is broken for me.

////////////////////

**UPDATE 2:**
I've checked a shortcut file on 'usr/local/php5' and it's refer to a wrong directory, so I rename it to 'php5-old' and created a new alias from my old php directory and rename it 'php5'.

When I run 'php -v' command, it says a different error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/php5/lib/libtidy-0.99.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/php5-7.3.0beta3-20180903-112811/bin/php
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/php5/lib/libtidy-0.99.0.dylib: stat() failed with errno=20
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I don't know what to do. I did check on that "libtidy-0.99.0.dylib" file, and still on the same directory.

////////////////////

**UPDATE 3:**
This is not the best practice. But I've got temporary solution already. I start to understand that the problem from my UPDATE 2 is from 'usr/local/php5', but instead I create a new alias that doesn't work, I rename the 'php5' refers directory and add "-old" prefix. And the original folder that should work "php5-7.3.0beta3-20180903-112811", I rename into the folder name that 'php5' alias refers to. And the PHP now working.

But still one more problem: "Apache web server" still not running.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache is "Unable to initialize module" because of module's and PHP's API don't match after changing the PHP configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394532/apache-is-unable-to-initialize-module-because-of-modules-and-phps-api-dont)

Comment: I've been check that right before I wrote my question, I did copy paste that command but the error shows: ```No installed keg or cask with the name "php5-mcrypt"```. I don't know what to write on the version part on that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this problem occurs when my Mac itself has another issue (which I'm not exactly sure about).

So the best solution so far (for Mac Users) which has proven to work for me, is to create a new Mac user and install PHP as if setting up a new laptop. This approach resolved the issue and returned the system to normal operation (I have tried to avoid this from the beginning).. Works Normal